# Finding unique emails across two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables one each with email address. I want all emails from table `a` that are not in table `b`.

Here is  my query, it seems to be hanging. I must have missed something..

```
SELECT c.Field_23_4306 AS email, c.Field_25_9341, c.Field_26_1838, c.Field_40_7355
FROM FORM_7 c
LEFT JOIN bounceback b ON c.Field_23_4306 = b.email
WHERE c.Field_23_4306 LIKE "%@%"
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.mail from a where not exists (select 1 from b where a.mail = b.mail)
```